# How can I get an ID from one table and place in another?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a simple news system, where the user can write a news story, and add a pic also.

I know the 'logic' behind what I need to do:

- Save the image details in the database and get the ID that was used when it was INSERTed
- Save the news story along with the picture ID I just got above

How can I populate `newsPicID` field in tblNews with the ID that was used when the pic was inserted into `picID` field in tblPic?

My INNER JOIN would then look something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM tblNews INNER JOIN picTable ON picTable.picID = newsTable.newsPicID
```

For any reference, here is my current code:

```
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
        {
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);  

            // Save files to disk
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/images/admin/news/" +  FileName));

            // Add Entry to DataBase
            String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles (FileName, FilePath) values(@FileName, @FilePath); insert into tblNews (newsTitle, newsDate, newsSummmary, newsContent) values(@newsTitle, @newsDate, @newsSummmary, @newsContent)"; 

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "/images/admin/news/" + FileName);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsTitle", txtnewstitle.Text);            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsDate", txtnewsdate.Text);            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsSummary", txtnewssummary.Text);            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsContent", txtnewsmaincontent.Text);            

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;

            try {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is picID an identity field?

Comment: @Vicky_Thinking yes. picID in tblFiles and newsID in tblNews are primary and identity

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to build an Stored Procedure to save both, file and news. Then you can use a transaction to control the whole operation.

Something similar to this:

```
create procedure dbo.NewsInsert
(@FileName varchar(65)
,@FilePath varchar(300)
,@newsTitle varchar(100)
,@newsDate DateTime
,@newsSummary varchar(100)
,@newsContent varchar(1024)
)
as
begin

    begin transaction

    insert into tblFiles (FileName, FilePath) 
    values(@FileName, @FilePath);

    if @@ERROR <> 0
    begin
        if @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        -- RAISE SOME ERROR -
    end

    -- I spouse tblFiles has some identity field as PICTURE_ID
    -- use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get it

    insert into tblNews (newsTitle, newsDate, newsSummmary, newsContent, PICTURE_ID) 
    values(@newsTitle, @newsDate, @newsSummmary, @newsContent, scope_identity());

    if @@ERROR <> 0
    begin
        if @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        -- RAISE SOME ERROR -
    end

    -- finally commit the transaction
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
end
```

Comment: Thanks @mcNets! I'm going to read up on stored procedures and test it out :-) Is there any reason why a stored procedure would work better here?

Comment: using a transaction you can ensure that both records or none has been inserted.